# Custom url based off single html input without JS

Tags: python, html, django

So I have probably the simplest task you could ever wish for with an html form that I cannot solve.

I want to input a brand name into a search bar, click submit and it redirect to the url/brand/[input]

I already have a working view for the urls setup in django. How would I structure the form to actually create my desired url?

```
  <form method="GET" action="">
     <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

views.py

```
class GetByBrand(ListView):
    def get(self, request, brand):
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', GetListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('brands/<str:brand>/', GetByBrand.as_view())
]
```

Comment: show Your views.py and urls.py

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form method="GET" action="brands/">
 <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

in URLs(import views by from. import views)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('brands/', views.GetByBrand),
]
```

in Views
from django.http import HttpResponse
def GetByBrand(request):
s = request.GET['brand']
return HttpResponse(s)

Answer (score 0):

OR use AJAX in Javascript in your HTML file

```
$('#brand').on('submit',function(e){
 var brand = $('input[name=brands]')
 $.get("brands/"+brand, function(data, status){
 alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
```

});
})

Answer (score 0):

So I basically solved this by using the code I had previously tried which is identical to what Wagas Develper recommended. What I had not done though was add this last line to the urls.py in the main project folder. (and I'm still not sure why this solved it but found the solution from throwing crap at the wall)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shoes.urls')),
    path('brands/', include('shoes.urls'))
```

For anyone curious about how the class based view is structured now.

```
class GetByBrand(ListView):

    def get(self, request, brand):

        get_results = request.GET.get('q')
```

The urls.py in the same directory as views.py (within app dir not main project dir)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', GetListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('brands/<str:brand>/', GetByBrand.as_view()),
    path('brand_results/', GetByBrand.as_view(), name='b')
]
```

HTML Form

```
  <form method="GET" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'b' %}">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 search-btn" type="text" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```